500 Internal Server Error for PHP Requests in Laravel Docker Setup
I am encountering a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to access PHP files in my Laravel project running in Docker, specifically occurring on GET /index.php. I am using Nginx and PHP-FPM with Docker.
Nginx Configuration (site.conf):
upstream backend {
    server web:9000;  # PHP-FPM service
}

server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name domain_name;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    client_max_body_size 100M;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass backend;  # Use the upstream backend
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

Docker Compose Configuration (docker-compose.yml):
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./docker/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    depends_on:
      - web

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_php
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - 9001:9000
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  db-data:

Dockerfile
FROM php:8.3-fpm

# Install system dependencies and PHP extensions
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip \
    git \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql mbstring zip

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Copy application code
COPY . .

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer:2.7 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Install PHP dependencies
RUN composer install

When accessing PHP files, I receive a 500 Internal Server Error. HTML files are served correctly, but PHP files are not processed.
These are the logs from the storage/logs directory:
tail -n 10 laravel.log
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(490): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->renderHttpException(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException))
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(356): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException))
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(196): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->render(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(ArgumentCountError))
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(173): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse(Object(ArgumentCountError))
#29 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(ArgumentCountError))
#30 {main}
  thrown at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php:94)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"} 

Steps Taken:
Verified that the index.php file is present in the /var/www/html/public directory. Ensured that the Nginx and PHP-FPM containers are running. Checked file permissions and ownership. Questions:
Are there any misconfigurations in my Nginx setup or Docker setup that could be causing this issue? How can I further troubleshoot this 500 Internal Server Error? Thank you for your assistance!

A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. For Laravel, also check in storage/logs.

I have edited the post @aynber

That's the very end of the stack trace (lines 25-30), you want where that error starts. It will start with a timestamp

Based on the error, it looks like Laravel is having trouble connecting to your database. Is it properly configured in config/database.php? Check the database log for errors, and if you still can find the problem, trying manually installing a sql client on the db container and connecting using the same parameters.

Resolved the issue by running composer install to ensure all dependencies were correctly installed.

Resolved the issue by running composer install to ensure all dependencies were correctly installed.
